# Get basename from filepath in bash

Tags: bash, terminal

I am trying to run a bash command using $1 variable which contains a filename and its path.

I want to log only the filename to an output.txt file but I am having difficulty stripping out the path from the variable.

I have tried the following:

```
file=$(basename $1)
echo ${file} >> output.txt

file=$(basename $1)
echo file >> output.txt

echo "basename $1" >> output.txt
```

None of them work, either return 'Data' or 'file'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, there are **2 pitfalls** here:

- **neglecting to double-quote parameter and variable references -`$1` or `$var` - and command substitutions - `$(...)` -**  making them subject to word splitting and globbing, which could *break* the overall command, or, worse, [*introduce security vulnerabilities*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/54804).
- less importantly so, **making sure that a command *operand* isn't mistaken for an *option***, if it happens to start with a `-` character, **by using `--`** to signal that everything following it is to be interpreted as an *operand*.

*Assigning* to a variable (double-quoting *optional*, but *recommended*):

```
# OK - but note that the $1 inside the $(...) IS double-quoted,
# because command substitutions are "their own world".
file=$(basename -- "$1")

# Better, just to get into the habit of double-quoting:
file="$(basename -- "$1")"
```

*Using* the variable - *always double-quote* (unless you explicitly want word-splitting and globbing):

```
echo "${file}" >> output.txt
```

---

As for **why your attempts didn't work**:

- `echo file >> output.txt` didn't work, because in order to reference variable `file` you must `$`-prefix it (i.e., `$file` and, for the reasons stated above, virtually always as `"$file"`).
- `echo "basename $1" >> output.txt` didn't work, because while *parameter* `$1` *is* expanded inside the double-quoted string, you need a *command substitution* - here, `$(basename "$1")` - to embed *commands* in a double-quoted string.
- `file=$(basename $1)`, due to lack of double-quoting of `$1`, would *only* work with `$1` values that contain no shell metacharacters (including spaces), and values that don't start with `-`; `echo ${file} >> output.txt` - again due to lack of double-quoting - could then inadvertently alter the value of `$file` again.

Comment: `file="$(basename -- "$1")"` made the syntax highlight and the view of code look bad with unnecessary double quote in RHS of assignment.

Comment: @cuonglm: That just means that the syntax highlighting is broken, not an indication that the double-quotes shouldn't be used. They're perfectly fine there, and habitually using them will keep you out of trouble. Yes, you _can_ omit them in _this_ scenario, if you know what you're doing (that's why I listed it as an option), but remembering when you actually _need_ them and when not can get tricky.

Comment: Yeah, of course. I said *unnecessary*, not meaning *shouldn't*.

Comment: @cuonglm: So if I understand you correctly, you were trying to say: the code may look funny here, but it is actually correct.  (On whether the syntax highlighting is broken: while the current representation isn't great, representing command substitutions that can be nested arbitrarily sounds like a tough nut to crack, short of introducing graduations of background shading, or something along those lines.)

Comment: @cuonglm: No worries; thanks for confirming the shared understanding.

Answer (score 3):

For the reason, see [@mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33336879/2218718).

---

The best way to get basename from file path in `bash` (or any other POSIX shells) should be:

```
printf '%s\n' "${filepath##*/}"
```

That's all, no external command, no process fork needed, just [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Another note that the use of [printf instead of echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/38906), which give you  more reliability and portability.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variable $1 contains an absolute filepath like e.g.

```
/home/user/dir/file1.txt
```

you got various methods of appending the filename to a file:

```
1. echo $(basename "$1") >> output.txt

2. file=$(basename "$1") && echo "$file" >> output.txt
```

there are tons of other possible solutions and even your first solution is working for me.

Comment: The lack of double-quoting in your answer makes it brittle, and while we don't know the specifics of the input that broke the OP's code, I suspect it's the very lack of double-quoting that caused it.

Comment: the `echo` in `echo $(basename "$1")` is useless (and wrong since the command substitution is not quoted).